# Can you help me develop this formula further?

Tags: excel

The below formula is designed to show the hyperlink of send when the cell referenced displays yes, however i need the formula to not show the send button unless the cell referenced explicitly says yes, so if i place in the cell referenced a - for example the hyperlink of send will not appear.

In essence i need the formula to be absolute in that it should only appear when the word yes appears.

Heres what i have thus far,

```
=IF(I7<>"",HYPERLINK("mailto:"&Sheet3!$B$1&"?subject="&Sheet3!$B$2&"&cc="&Sheet3!$B$3&"&body="&Sheet3!$B$4,"SEND"),"")
```

I hope you can help,

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just mean that cell I7 in your example has to say yes, all you need is to change

```
=IF(I7<>"",...
```

to

```
=IF(I7="yes",...
```

If you want it to just have to contain 'yes'

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("yes",I7)),...
```

Excel has a built-in boolean type, so if you can change 'yes' to TRUE/FALSE, you could just use
    =IF(I7,...

Comment: Thank you very very much indeed, your second option has cured the problem. Truly grateful for your help.